# Enabling Accessibility

Tags: electron

How can add this code to Electron Application from Mac OS?

```
CFStringRef kAXManualAccessibility = CFSTR("AXManualAccessibility");

+ (void)enableAccessibility:(BOOL)enable inElectronApplication:(NSRunningApplication *)app
{
    AXUIElementRef appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(app.processIdentifier);
    if (appRef == nil)
        return;

    CFBooleanRef value = enable ? kCFBooleanTrue : kCFBooleanFalse;
    AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(appRef, kAXManualAccessibility, value);
    CFRelease(appRef);
}
```

I'm confused by the instructions: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v2.0.0-beta.6/docs/tutorial/accessibility.md#enabling-accessibility

Yes i am beginner, I just want to learn about this electron feature. thanks .